# go-getter and context deadline exceeded

Tags: go

I would like to use [go-getter v2](https://github.com/hashicorp/go-getter/tree/v2) to download from http some huge zip files and have them unpacked.

I try this code (note: [defaultProgressBar](https://github.com/hashicorp/go-getter/blob/v2/cmd/go-getter/progress_tracking.go) taken from here)

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "log"

    getter "github.com/hashicorp/go-getter/v2"
)

func main() {
    ctx := context.Background()
    req := &getter.Request{
        Src:              "https://huge-file.zip",
        Dst:              "data/",
        Pwd:              "./",
        GetMode:          getter.ModeAny,
        ProgressListener: defaultProgressBar,
    }
    // client := getter.DefaultClient
    client := getter.Client{}
    _, err := client.Get(ctx, req)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

This code always returns `context deadline exceeded`. What should i known about context usage?

Comment: `2023/03/25 15:30:18 context deadline exceeded
exit status 1`

Comment: there is only one err catch in that script

Comment: Sorry, you `log.Fatal(err)` this isn't a stack trace scenario my bad

Comment: the most important thing to know about context is that it was designed specificaly to handle sitatuations where you want to cancel an HTTP request, because the server timed out, even though it can be used for more general purposes. This indicates to me that your `https://huge-file.zip` is timing out, possibly because it was expecting different request headers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the doc for [getter.Client](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/hashicorp/go-getter/v2#Client):

> ```golang
> type Client struct {
>   // Getters is the list of protocols supported by this client. If this
>   // is nil, then the default Getters variable will be used.
>   Getters []Getter
>
>   // other fields are omitted.
> }
> ```

And the `HttpGetter` in the default `Getters` is configured with a `ReadTimeout` of **30s** (see the [source code](https://github.com/hashicorp/go-getter/blob/544f3d752be3b5396bf9030280bb7449f804173e/get.go#L73-L78)):

```golang
httpGetter := &HttpGetter{
    Netrc:                 true,
    XTerraformGetDisabled: true,
    HeadFirstTimeout:      10 * time.Second,
    ReadTimeout:           30 * time.Second,
}
```

So the error is reported by the default `HttpGetter`. If the huge file takes more than 30s to download, you should configure the `HttpGetter` with a reasonable value. See the demo below:

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httptest"
    "time"

    getter "github.com/hashicorp/go-getter/v2"
)

func main() {
    ts := httptest.NewServer(http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        w.Write([]byte{'a'})
        time.Sleep(31 * time.Second)
        w.Write([]byte{'b'})
    }))
    defer ts.Close()

    ctx := context.Background()
    req := &getter.Request{
        Src:     ts.URL,
        Dst:     "data.txt",
        Pwd:     "./",
        GetMode: getter.ModeAny,
    }
    client := &getter.Client{
        Getters: []getter.Getter{
            &getter.HttpGetter{
                Netrc:                 true,
                XTerraformGetDisabled: true,
                HeadFirstTimeout:      10 * time.Second,
                // Set the ReadTimeout to a reasonable value for the huge file.
                ReadTimeout: 60 * time.Second,
            },
        },
    }

    log.Println("begin downloading")

    _, err := client.Get(ctx, req)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    log.Println("done!")
}
```